# how much pull left for docker hub rate limit?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am trying to find out a way to check how much pulls i have left but this page https://www.docker.com/blog/checking-your-current-docker-pull-rate-limits-and-status/ does not really explain that

the page only explains how to find the rate limit plan, either anonymous or authenticated BUT i want to find out how much pulls i have left for docker pulls

Is there a way i can find this stat? Check how much pulls i have left within the time limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit/, requests to the manifest API receive the following headers:

```
RateLimit-Limit    
RateLimit-Remaining
```

the latter one being the one you're interested in.

Answer (score 4):

I've written a [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) project that includes regctl that recently added an `image ratelimit` command. It uses an HTTP HEAD request to avoid using any quota in checking your current rate limit:

```
$ regctl image ratelimit regclient/regctl
{
  "Remain": 2500,
  "Limit": 2500,
  "Reset": 0,
  "Set": true
}
```

If the command has access to your `~/.docker` folder, or you run a `registry login`, it will use your credentials to give the limit that applies to yourself rather than anonymous user rates applied to your IP address.

There's also [this blog post](https://www.docker.com/blog/checking-your-current-docker-pull-rate-limits-and-status/) that shows how to do this with curl and jq commands. The following is an example with anonymous requests to a specific test repo:

```
TOKEN=$(curl "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:ratelimitpreview/test:pull" | jq -r .token)
curl -v -I -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ratelimitpreview/test/manifests/latest 2>&1 | grep -i RateLimit
```

Comment: This command helped a lot for us.  If you find you get stuck and really need an image on a node in prod, and you're rate limited, you can manually move it on, avoiding the pull like this.  https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2021/11/03/manually-load-docker-image-avoid-rate-limiting/. Saved us recently.  The whole "you may have 500 nodes but they use 5 or 6 nat gateways" thing hurts a lot on enterprise systems =(.

Comment: @JohnHumphreys If you're running a large cluster, I recommend running your own mirror of Hub. Sync the images you depend on to avoid the risk of an outage from something that happened upstream out of your control. See regclient/regsync for a useful tool to copy images to your local mirror.

Comment: Thanks BMitch.  Yeah, we put most images in GitLab to avoid it at this point.  We’re also checking out GitLab dependency proxy, Harbor, and Open Policy Agent rules as options.  I’ll add this to the list though!  It’s new to me.

Comment: Seems like the header is now lower-case, so you'd have to `grep ratelimit` in the jq example (or use `grep -i`).